# На вход строка, на выходе массив чисел

Tags: java

На вход строка, на выходе массив чисел - это общее, что надо сделать. Например:

```
“12 13 14”  => [12, 13, 14] 
“1b1d3f5”   => [1, 3, 5] 
“-123—v123” => [-123, 123]
```

Как я делал.
Сразу скажу, что я строку разбиваю на символы и уже символы сравниваю. Делаю так, чтобы не зависеть от разделителей. Проверяю каждый символ!

```
public class Exercise5 {
    int[] arr2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise5 ex5 = new Exercise5();

         int[] result = ex5.parseString4("12.325.6.nunnv13");
         String output = Arrays.toString(result);
         System.out.println(output);
    }

    public int[] parseString4(String input) {

        if (input.isEmpty()) {
            return null      
        }
        arr2 = new int[input.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char ch = input.charAt(i);
            arr2[i] = Character.digit(ch, 10);  
        }
        return arr2; 
    }
}
```

В этом месте я получаю

> ```
> [1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 3, -1, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1]
> ```

И вот здесь у меня возникает ряд проблем. У меня получается два типа чисел. Первые - положительные, вторые - отрицательные.

1. Надо положительные числа
       записывать (!!!) одним числом, например:
       индекс 0,1 - это положительные числа,
       которые складывают одно целое число.
       Как это реализовать?  Чтобы было не
       1,2, а 12!!
2. Надо сделать переход при
       отрицательном числе.

Возможно, я выбрал неправильный способ решения, так как я пока не учел отрицательные числа, которые стоят в условии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class Main {


    private static final String REGEX="-?[0-9]+";
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String numbers ="12-36-ds-be 12 -12";
        List list = new ArrayList();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(numbers);
        while(m.find()){
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
        }

        int[] result = new int[list.size()];

        for (int i=0; i< list.size(); i++){
            result[i] = (int) list.get(i);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

}
```

Comment: используй технологию regexp, просто ищешь в строке все подстроки содержащие цифры, и которые могут иметь или не иметь знак минуса передтпоследовательностью цифр.